# Setting up multiple login options for Mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki

Is it possible to set up my wiki so that when user login, they have options to either login through OpenIDConnect (which i already have set up on my wiki) or login through the normal Mediawiki login?

Comment: sorry if that wasn't clear, i meant so that the user can choose between logging in using OpenIDConnect OR just use the normal login.

Comment: This is controlled by `$wgPluggableAuth_EnableLocalLogin` (https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:PluggableAuth).

Answer (score 0):

enable `$wgPluggableAuth_EnableLocalLogin = true` to do this